# Ошибка с классом Bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, bitmap

Помогите решить данную проблему в коде

```
public void draw(int x,int y)
{
    var map = new Bitmap("Result.png");
    map.SetPixel(x0+x, y0+y, Color.Black);            
    map.Save("Result.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    map.Dispose();
}
```

Необработанное исключение типа

> "System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException" в System.Drawing.dll Дополнительные сведения: В GDI+ возникла ошибка общего вида.

StackTrace:

```
в System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
в System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
в Encryption.Form1.draw(Int32 x, Int32 y) в C:\Users\Ivang\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Encryption\Encryption\Form1.cs:строка 44
в Encryption.Form1.library(Char symb) в C:\Users\Ivang\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Encryption\Encryption\Form1.cs:строка 54
в Encryption.Form1.action() в C:\Users\Ivang\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Encryption\Encryption\Form1.cs:строка 191
```

Comment: Попробуйте переместить строчку `map.Dispose();` на одну ниже. Т.е. `map.Save("Result.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);map.Dispose();`

Comment: @FoggyFinder не решило проблему

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH, вставь stacktrace и полный текст ошибки, а не картинку

Comment: ну и не исключено, что ты просто не можешь сохранить в **уже открытый** файл. Попробуй сменить имя в `Save`, например на `Result2.png`.

Comment: и еще добавь пример `x0, y0` с которыми вызываешь.

Comment: @Grundy а если мне эту картинку несколько раз за работу программы придётся открывать? Каждый раз при сохранении менять название?

Comment: не обязательно, но сначала нужно определиться с причиной текущей ошибки, и потом разбираться со следующей ошибкой

Comment: @Grundy вот такой текст ошибки, больше ничего не показывает 

Необработанное исключение типа "System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException" в System.Drawing.dll

Дополнительные сведения: В GDI+ возникла ошибка общего вида.

Comment: это все в сам вопрос добавляй, можно даже **вместо** картинок

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49790/discussion-between-grundy-and-zoom-smash).

Answer (score 4):

```
public void draw(int x,int y)
{
    var map = new Bitmap("Result.png");
    map.SetPixel(x0+x, y0+y, Color.Black);            
    // !!! В этом месте файл всё ещё заблокирован!
    // !!! И таким останется до уничтожения битмапа
    // !!! Сейчас в него писать нельзя
    //map.Save("Result.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    map.Dispose();
    // !!! Теперь в файл писать можно
    // !!! Но писать уже нечего, т. к. картинка уничтожена
}
```

Возможные варианты решения (выбрать любой):

- Считать файл в память и создать Bitmap из MemoryStream
- Создать другой bitmap того же размера и нарисовать первый на нём
  Тут надо быть осторожнее с форматом пикселей
- Записать в другой файл, потом удалить первый и переименовать второй

А ещё вместо явного вызова Dispose следует использовать блок `using`.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала нужно понять, что происходит в вашем коде. Там всего четыре строчки, поэтому это не трудно.

1. Вы создаете объект. Загружаете в него изображение из файла
2. Вы изменяете этот объект.
3. Вы удаляете объект из памяти.
4. Вы пытаетесь сохранить объект, который уже удалил.

Очевидно, что вам требуется поменять местами строки 3 и 4

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло

Answer (score 1):

```
public void draw(int x,int y)
{
  Bitmap map2 = null;
  try
  {
    using (Bitmap map1 = new Bitmap("Result.png"))
    {
      map2 = (Bitmap)map1.Clone();
    }

    map2.SetPixel(x0+x, y0+y, Color.Black);            
    map2.Save("Result.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
  }
  finally
  {
    if (map2 != null)
      map2.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: лучше уж using использовать. И для второго - тоже :)

Comment: @Grundy не, дла второго - не лучше, эти `using`ы пересекаются

Comment: ну и что?  и что значит пересекаются?  один просто внутри другого - это нормально. Нарисовав try...finally - ты просто сразу раскрыл второй using

Comment: @Grundy не вложены, а пересекаются

Comment: тогда по твоей логике у тебя сейчас using пересекается с try...finally :) и кстати скобку у try забыл закрывающую